# Membase Java Load Generator Problem

Tags: java, load, memcached, generator, membase

I am trying to run Java Load Generator provided in membase documentation (http://techzone.couchbase.com/wiki/display/membase/Load+Generator+Setup)

Firstly, I modified workloadb file and mentioned membase server address into it.

WORKLOADB FILE CONTENT :
db=com.yahoo.ycsb.db.SpymemcachedClient

memcached.address=10.72.45.165

memcached.port=11211

slaveaddress=10.112.83.64

histogram.buckets=20

exportfile=results.txt

recordcount=200000

operationcount=500000

workload=com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.MemcachedCoreWorkload

## insertstart=200000

readallfields=true

insertproportion=0

readproportion=0.95

updateproportion=0

scanproportion=0

## memaddproportion=0.05

memgetproportion=0.100

## memsetproportion=0.25

memupdateproportion=0.0

## memappendproportion=0.05

## memprependproportion=0.05

## memreplaceproportion=0.05

## memcasproportion=0.05

valuelength=2048

workingset=100000

churndelta=100000

printstatsinterval=5

requestdistribution=zipfian

threadcount=4

Then, I build whole load generator project by using command : ant decompile-memcached
And Tried to load data using command :
 java -cp build/ycsb.jar:lib/memcached-2.5-14-g3b3b3c8.jar:lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.2.jar:lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.2.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar:lib/memcached-2.5-27-gc7bc636-sources.jar:lib/memcached-2.6.jar com.yahoo.ycsb.LoadGenerator -load -P worloads/workloadb

After issuing this command, I got the terminal output :

0 sec:  0 operations; 0 ops/sec

2011-05-24 17:05:54.022 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/10.72.45.165:11222, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue

2011-05-24 17:05:54.026 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/10.72.45.165:11222, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue

2011-05-24 17:05:54.027 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/10.72.45.165:11222, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue

2011-05-24 17:05:54.036 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/10.72.45.165:11222, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue

2011-05-24 17:05:54.046 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for user76958204.

2011-05-24 17:05:54.047 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for user336694473.

2011-05-24 17:05:54.048 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for user1268118805.

2011-05-24 17:05:54.058 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Could not redistribute to another node, retrying primary node for user1681771482.

Can anyone please point out the mistake ? I have three membase servers running in cluster. I am not able to understand what does this error mean.

Regards,

Sanket Dangi

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. I wrote the code for this a while back and haven't contributed to it at all since then. The purpose fo the project was for my own personal benchmarking and while it certainly got me good results there are many issues with the project and I was unable to find time to stabilize it. This makes it difficult for others to use at the moment. I do want to mention though that any memcached load generator will work with Membase since Membase is on the wire compatible with memcached. If your still trying to get some benchmarking results from Membase I want to suggest taking a look at https://github.com/couchbaselabs/gamesim. This a workload simulator that simulates players playing a simple game.

If I am able to find time to improve and stabilize this project I will update this post.